# Can not add favicon to my Django app

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm using Django 2.06 to develop an application. I'm trying to add Favicon but it's not working in my app.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}" type='image/x-icon' >
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}" type='image/x-icon'>
```

I have mentioned `{% load static %}` at `base.html` file as well.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .views import HomeView, article_details, ArticleListView, 
 ProductPageView, ContactPageView 

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'), 
    path('details/<int:id>/<slug:slug>', article_details, name='article-details'),
    path('articles/', ArticleListView.as_view(), name='article-list-view'),
    path('products/', ProductPageView.as_view(), name='product-page-view'), 
    path('contact/', ContactPageView.as_view(), name='contact-page-view'), 
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I ran the link and it does not work..

```
'favicon\favicon.ico' could not be found
http://localhost:8000/static/favicon/favicon.ico
```

Comment: Can you access the `favicon.ico` itself (through the proposed URL)?

Comment: Did you run collectstatic?

Comment: @ guillermo chamorro  i ran collectstatic and it's same, does not work.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem  yes this link is working. i checked it thorugh Ctrl+U .

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, accept my apology, the proposes link is not working but my location direction is ok.

Comment: Try adding {% static 'favicon/favicon.ico' %} in href. (assuming you have the icon inside the folder favicon) I&amp;#39;m not sure about thia but in my experience the static refers to only the static folder and the rest of the path has to mentioned manually.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply. I have solved this way back. In the Django localhost favicon did not work but pythonanywhere host runs favicon properly.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone with this problem:

First of all check the link is working (i.e: localhost:8000/static/images/favicon.ico)

If the link is working and you can actually see your icon, that means that the only reason your favicon is not showing yet is because of your navigator's cache.

Restart your navigator (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.) and when you open it again you should be able to see it updated.